# How to prove $m(A)＝0$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and is Lebesgue measurable. For $d$ arbitrary small, we have $d+A=A$. (here $d+A=\{d+a:a\in A\}$) Prove $m(A)＝0$ or $m(A^C)＝0$.

I assume $m(A^C)＞0$ and try to prove $m(A)=0$. But I can't figure out what to do next. It seems that I should construst some $f(x)$ corresponding to $A+x$ and then integral it by Fubini Thm to have $m(A^C)$.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the question.

Comment: As it stands $\mathbb Q$ is a counter-example.

Comment: yeah，you are right. I have just fixed it.

Comment: Is $d$ fixed or not? When you say "for $d$ arbitrarily small" I read "there is some $\epsilon$ for which if $d<\epsilon$ then $A + d = A$. If that's the case, then for any $x \in A$, the interval $[x,x=\epsilon]\subset A$ which means $A$ has positive measure unless $A$ is the empty set.

Comment: For any ε＞0, there is a d such that d(ε)＜ε and d satisfies d+A＝A. d is not fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First assume that there is a dense sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n+A=A$ for all $n$. If $m(A)>0$ and $m(A^{c})>0$ then $\exists $ $a<b$ such that $(a,b)\subset
A-A^{c}.$

[Sketch of proof: the convolution $I_{A}\ast I_{A^{c}}$ is continuous. If it is
identically $0$ we get a contradiction by noting that its integral is $%
m(A)m(A^{c})>0$. Hence it is positive on some interval $(a,b)$].

Also there is an interger $n$ such that $-x_{n}\in (a,b).$ But then $-x_{n}=x-y$ with $%
x\in A,y\in A^{c}$ so $y=x+x_{n}\in x_{n}+A=A,$ a contradiction.

Now for the general case just observe that $\{nx_m:  n \in \mathbb Z, m \geq 1\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ where $(x_m)$ is sequence of distinct numbers tending to $0$ such that $x_m+A=A$ for all $m$.

Comment: Actually, I think it can only obtain that there is some $(a,b)\in A+A^C$. But this method is enough to solve this question. Thanks a lot！